# Surface with Kahler-Einstein metric

Tags: kahler-manifolds, complex-manifolds, kahler-einstein-metric

Let $3\leq k\leq 8$ be an integer. Suppose $M$ is a complex surface which has a Kahler-Einstein metric and has the same Betti numbers as $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2\# k\overline{\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2}$, i.e. 
$$b_0(M)=b_4(M)=1,~~ b_1(M)=b_3(M)=0,~~b_2^+(M)=1,~~ b_2^-(M)=k.$$
Then can we conclude that $M$ is biholomorphic to $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2\# k\overline{\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2}$?

**Note added**: The answer of Martin de Borbon has shown that this is not true for $5\leq k\leq 8$. I would like to know if the statement is true for $k=3, 4$.

Comment: Perhaps you should add simply connected. Otherwise Enriques surfaces satisfy all the above, with k=9

Comment: @MartindeBorbon Thanks for the comment. I think I understand what you said. And it justifies why I put the condition $3\leq k\leq 8$ in the beginning.

Comment: Right, but I still think you should add the hypothesis that M is simply connected. Otherwise blow ups of fake projective spaces at k points are counter examples

Comment: I am trying to understand what you said....are you saying the blow ups of fake projective spaces have Kahler-Einstein metric?

Comment: my mistake, no these are not, the canonical is not ample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There answer is no. The topological manifolds $\mathbb{CP}^2 \sharp k \overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}$ admit smooth structures that support KE with negative scalar curvature for k=5, 6, 7, 8

For k=8, see  https://arxiv.org/pdf/dg-ga/9705007.pdf

For k=6, 7, see https://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.1424.pdf

For k=5, see https://msp.org/gt/2009/13-3/gt-v13-n3-p06-p.pdf

Comment: I see. I wonder if the statement is true for $k=3,4$. I will try to wait and see if there is any result for $k=3,4$. If not, I will accept your answer. Thanks.